# MVC and Winforms share code

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller, dll

I have an MVC webapp and am creating a Winforms app.  The methods I have created and use in the MVC app will also be used by the Winforms app.  Is there a way I can share the code between them so that I can update it all in one place?  Maybe turn those methods into a dll that they both use?  If so, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Look up "class library".

Comment: That was it, got one up and running now, thanks!